# How to add query string to <BaseURL> in mpeg-dash?

Tags: mpeg-dash, drm

I am trying to play the video with mpeg-dash, indeed, the source video must be accessed with signed query strings , so I appended query strings to `<BaseURL>` tag like the following dash file , but it does not work well.

```
<AdaptationSet id="1" contentType="video" maxWidth="1280" maxHeight="720" frameRate="90000/3750" subsegmentAlignment="true" par="16:9">
      <Representation id="1" bandwidth="1168165" codecs="avc1.64000d" mimeType="video/mp4" sar="1:1" width="320" height="180">
        <ContentProtection value="cenc" schemeIdUri="urn:mpeg:dash:mp4protection:2011" cenc:default_KID="41b2cf69-7a0e-46bb-9b56-45ac2e775a26"/>
        <ContentProtection schemeIdUri="urn:uuid:edef8ba9-79d6-4ace-a3c8-27dcd51d21ed">
          <cenc:pssh>AAAANXBzc2gAAAAA7e+LqXnWSs6jyCfc1R0h7QAAABUiEzUyODU4OTA3OTMxMTczOTkzNDk=</cenc:pssh>
        </ContentProtection>
        <BaseURL>1.mp4?t=5d662215&sign=e2ec251dd73ac43afd377ddf849ba81d</BaseURL>
        <SegmentBase indexRange="1133-1944" timescale="90000">
          <Initialization range="0-1132"/>
        </SegmentBase>
      </Representation>
    </AdaptationSet>
```

So how can I make the player access 1.mp4 with query strings `t` and `sign` ?Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the `'&'` in you query string with `'&amp;'`.

So try:

```
<BaseURL>1.mp4?t=5d662215&amp;sign=e2ec251dd73ac43afd377ddf849ba81d</BaseURL>
```

Guidelines for Implementation: DASH-IF Interoperability Points (Version 4.3)

Give an example for the use of query parameters:

5.3.3.2.1.2. Example 2: Stateful cue translation

The operator targets separately male and female audiences. Hence, the generator derives this from
the information it has regarding the requesting client (see 5.1.3.6), and inserts an XLink URL with
the query parameter **?gender=male** for male viewers, and **?gender=female** for the female viewers.

Comment: You are welcome - feel free to mark my answer as correct - thanks.

Comment: Your solution is not working. I tested it with dash.js and the player will just drop the query string. I don't think this is a reliable way to do so. The spec is not clear about that so that'd be left to the player implementation.